# Phonegap/cordova App Has Stopped on Galaxy S5 and Note 4

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.example" version="1.0.0" versionCode="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>Rustic Plumbing Leak Cam</name>
<description>
  An example for phonegap build docs.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="https://build.phonegap.com">
  Hardeep Shoker
</author>
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<icon src="www/res/icon.png" />
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <splash src="www/res/splash.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/Icon-36.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/Icon-48.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/Icon-72.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/Icon-96.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/Icon-144.png" />
    <icon platform="android" qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/Icon-192.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-180.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-120.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-152.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-167.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-29.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-58.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-87.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-80.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-120.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-114.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-144.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/Icon-100.png" width="100" />
</platform>
<platform name="winphone">
    <icon height="30" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-30.png" width="30" />
    <icon height="44" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-44.png" width="44" />
    <icon height="50" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="70" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-70.png" width="70" />
    <icon height="71" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-71.png" width="71" />
    <icon height="106" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-106.png" width="106" />
    <icon height="120" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-120.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="150" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-150.png" width="150" />
    <icon height="170" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-170.png" width="170" />
    <icon height="310" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-310.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="360" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-360.png" width="360" />
    <icon height="99" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-99.png" width="99" />
    <icon height="159" platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/Icon-159.png" width="159" />
</platform>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="~1.4.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="your usage message" />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="your usage message" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email" spec="~1.2.6" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="~0.1.21" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git" />
<plugin source="git" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" />
<plugin source="git" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~1.0.1" />
 <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature> -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="~1.0.0" />
<engine name="android" spec="~6.2.3" />
</widget>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.phonegap.example" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.FirebasePluginInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="org.apache.cordova.firebase.OnNotificationOpenReceiver" />
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: would you specify more details regarding the issue? Symptom, screenshot, error message, and the efforts you have made?

Comment: i tried to downgrade the cordova into 5.0 still now working, https://www.screencast.com/t/GS5kpOtis1 here is the screenshot,

Comment: What actions/functions are you doing which is causing it to stop? can you provide Error messages shown in Console?  [inspect in Google Chrome]-> http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/ha8kbIGe a lot of error, but when i remove the cordova,js will clean the error, but when i test is in S5 Still now working